# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" with Ionic Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cakephp, syntax-error

I am using Angular JS to call an API on my CakePHP server. It adds a new customer to the MySQL database:

```
  $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
    if (isValid) {
      $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'https://www.something.com/customers/add.json',
        data    : $.param($scope.formData), 
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
      })
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.success == false) {
          $scope.error = data.message;
        } else {
          $scope.message = data.message; 
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

When adding a new entity fails, I get the correct answer (if condition):
[image]

When the entity can be added I get this (else condition):

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10063:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18080:16)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18171:12
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:20)
    at transformData (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18170:3)
    at transformResponse (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18926:23)
    at processQueue (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23399:28)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23415:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24678:28)
```

On the serverside (where the answer is generated) it looks like this:

```
if ($this->Customer->save($this->request->data)) {
    $message = 'Adding customer was successful, thanks!';
    $success = true;
} else {
    $message = 'Adding customer failed, please try again.';
    $success = false;
}

$this->set('_serialize', array('message', 'success'));
$this->set(compact('message', 'success'));
```

Why do I keep getting the Syntax Error for the else-condition?

Comment: What does `$this->Customer->invalidFields();` generate in the success case?

Comment: Looks like the response isn't valid JSON?

Comment: Even when I completely remove the variable `$reason` I get the same error. @AdamJeffers, the JSON string for success and error are almost identical.

Comment: Almost identical? What do you see in your console when logging out `data.message` in your else block?

Comment: Nothing, for the else condition I only see the error, no console output at all.

Comment: Yes, but if you `console.log(data.message)` directly inside your else block, what do you see? Or do you not even reach the else block?

Comment: If I do that I still see nothing, it seems like it crashes before it even can show a console output.

Comment: @AdamJeffers, you were right, I debugged the response using Googles developer tools and it turned out the response contained debug information. Of course that could not be parsed by Angular. I disabled the debugging output and now it works. If you write this in an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments... this is because the success response is not valid JSON.

Try debugging the output in the console and fix accordingly ;-)